# Take multiple arguments in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I have a batch file test.bat
I understand we can give it multiple arguments and take those values using %1, %2, and so on. But I do not know how many arguments will be given. I thought of constructing an array and for loop to decide. But the point I am failing is constructing the `for loop`.

what I did is:

```
set count=0
// for loop until we have arguments left
set list[%count%]=%var%
set /A count=count+1
```

I know little bit of `for loop` in batch files, but I do not quite understand how to use in this scenario. Number of arguments are unknown. Any direction would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%* contains all arguments.
you could

```
for %%a in (%*) do echo %%a
```

or use shift, which advances %1 to the next argument and so on.

```
 :loop
   echo %1
   shift
  if "%1" neq "" goto :loop
```